# Properties of S_n = 1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$.  Are the following  correct?

1. $S_{2^n}\geq \frac{n}{2}$
2. $\frac{S_n}{n}\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.

$S_{2^n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \dfrac{1}{k}$.

Proceeding by induction we have $S_2=1+\dfrac{1}{2}\geq \dfrac{1}{2}$.Assume that $S_{2^n}\geq \frac{n}{2}$;then $S_{2^{n+1}}=(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n})+(\frac{1}{2^n+1}+....+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})\geq \frac{n}{2}+(\frac{1}{2^n+1}+....+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$.

How to show that $(\frac{1}{2^n+1}+....+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})\geq \frac{1}{2}$??Please help here.

How should I check 2?? $\dfrac{S_n}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}}{n}=??$

Comment: How many term are there in $(\frac{1}{2^n+1} +\ldots+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$? Each of these terms is larger or equal to $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: Limits don't converge. They either exist or they don't.

Answer (score 0):

a) This is the Cauchy condensation test. Note that there are $2^n$ terms from $2^n+1$ to $2^{n+1}$.

b) could be attempted using the theorem of Stolz-Cesaro. However, the limit there would be $0$.

Could it be that it is $S_{2^n}/n$ that is to consider? Which would then lead to consider the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac1k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac1{1+2^{-n}k}=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x}dx=\ln2
$$

Or is the limit the one of $S_n/\ln(n)$? Then Cesaro-Stolz states that it is equal to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n}{\ln(n)-\ln(n-1)}
=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(1-\frac1n)}=1
$$